# bash - npm not found, though installed

Tags: bash, npm

```
ph@vm:~$ uname -a
Linux vm 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ph@vm:~$ which npm
/home/ph/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm

ph@vm:~$ npm -v
2.14.2

ph@vm:~$ cat .bash_profile 
export PATH="$PATH:/home/ph/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm"
```

I created a bash script file, `chmod +x`, but when running it `"Open with Terminal Emulator"`, it says:

```
npm: not found
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's exactly what's in your ~/.bash_profile, then you have a simple typo: the PATH variable should be a list of *directories* to search, not down to the specific command itself. Write instead:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/ph/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin"
```

Comment: I changed it, but still not found...

Comment: Can you paste the script file into your Question? Is it resetting $PATH, or calling npm with a specific path?

Comment: Since you are running it through the gui, did you log out and log in again? Or made otherwise sure the gui knows of your new path? It might not read those config files for every script.

Comment: Good point, Jakob -- I keep referring to http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile and indeed, a non-login bash shell does not read ~/.bash_profile. Logging out & in would fix the problem, as would putting the PATH at the top of the script.

Comment: After restarting it now works fine. Thank you